# Can I control main volume (main signal) with envelopes or LFO in FM8?

Tags: synthesizer

I am new to [Native Instruments - FM8](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/synths/fm8/), up until now I have been using [Native Instruments - Massive](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/synths/massive/). I am getting my grasps on how the **envelopes** and **LFO**'s work within FM8, I was wondering if there was a way I could link an **envelope** or **LFO** directly to the volume (main signal) of my synth?

*Is this something (or anything like this) I could do ?*

Any tips/help or advice(s) is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tell me my explanation is unclear I will correct it Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't but you can add an LFO/Envelope on the Oscillator/Filter/Saturation and finally Pitch object.

One thing you could do is having only one oscillator on output (modulated and even modulating other oscillators) then modulate it with an LFO/Envelope.

You could also use an external LFO plugin like [Xfer Records - LFOTools](https://www.xferrecords.com/products/lfotool) or [TAL - TAL-Filter-2](https://tal-software.com/products/tal-filter), the only thing you need to look at carefully is how your LFO is triggered if you can't trigger it with a note event then you might have to do an audio render of your synth when you like it or you will probably have some random render while playing your sound.